# EditText background color samsung devices

Tags: android

Hey I am having an issue where on stock android my edittext views have the transparent background with the underline but on samsung devices it is a solid black background which looks really bad with black text. I want to stop samsung from setting the background to black.

I have tried `android:background="#00ffffff"` 
but this removes the background from stock android which i want to keep.

Comment: maybe try this android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: #00ffffff sets the background to transparent. Both methods have the same effect

Comment: I have the issue in reverse. My S7 and S5 look perfect.  When I put the app on a LG p870 with 4.0.4, the backgrounds go black.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite late but incase someone still having same issue.Samsung set background as black when not defined any color as background.

**Solution** : So you have to set background color as transparent.

```
<solid android:color="@color/transparent" > </solid>
```